# Ubuntu change the left, right microphone sound card's level

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, microphone

I have some problems with my sound card which is solved by unbalancing the left and right mic level via pulse audio input level option as you can see:

[image: Volume control]

But it will be adjusted automatically after some seconds and I don't know why this happen, maybe Skype is doing that, but I don't find the  `allows Skype to automatically control...` instruction in my Skype as you can see:

[Edit 1. In Skype's Options --> Sound uncheck the tick that allows Skype to automatically control the volume settings.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628053/microphone-volume-changing-randomly)

[image: Skyoe settings]

Or maybe chrome is changing its level by webinar sites settings. But it would be solved by changing the left && right Mic level by my self.

I have also tried to change `Element Capture` by using `sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-internal-mic.conf` ,as you can see here:

```
[Element Capture]
switch = mute
volume = 50
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

And `sudo alsa force-reload` as said in [How to disable microphone volume auto adjustment in Cisco Webex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689209/how-to-disable-microphone-volume-auto-adjustment-in-cisco-webex). But it does not work and the mic level is changing by itself!

Also I have both OS version **20.10** and **18.04**, and now I am using the **20.10** but i have this problem in my Ubuntu 18.04 and I think it is not related to OS version.

**Update:**

More info :

```
$  lspci | grep  -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

**Update2:**

I have found, it would stay on the manually adjusted right and left mic level as shown below, by changing the **all input device** levels manually (not only  one of them!):

[image: volume control]

But I don't know it would not be changed by itself during the webinar and... I would test it tomorrow and if I don't forget, I would write here about its connection setting.

**New Update:**

It is stable in many times but sometimes it would be reset and needs to adjust again by hand, which i think Some unknown apps changes the left& right setting rarely in my Ubuntu OS, but during these days ( around 4 days) less that 3 times happens).

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering with the same problem as you are.
I did the following:

1. Went to `usr/share/pulseaudio/alsamixer/paths/analog-input-front-mic.config`
2. In [Element Front Mic Boost] I changed `volume = merge` to `volume = 40`
3. In [Element Front Mic] I changed `volume = merge` to `volume = 40`

My microphone sound card levels aren't magically changing, no more, so this solution worked for me. Let me know if you have any success.