# Ubuntu keeps auto adjusting its microphone input volume regardless of the app I am using

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, android-studio

Whenever I am building my project on Android Studio, for some reason the microphone volume goes to 100 without notifying me, and when I next join a call with somebody, they get annoyed because of my input volume.

Also, if I am using some audio recording tool like vocaroo.com, speaking too loud lowers the volume as well, which is very annoying.

It happens in other scenarios as well, whenever something is using my mic and the audio it is hearing is too low it tries to pick up the sound by turning up my input volume. This gets annoying as some apps don't turn the volume down when the volume is too high. I think some apps request the system to turn the volume up or down but this isn't the case on Windows. Is there a way I can block all these requests from those apps that want to mess with my input volume?

I tried everything suggested in:

- [How to disable microphone from auto adjusting its input volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279407/how-to-disable-microphone-from-auto-adjusting-its-input-volume)
- [How to disable microphone volume auto adjustment in Cisco Webex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689209/how-to-disable-microphone-volume-auto-adjustment-in-cisco-webex)

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way I can fix my dB gain and input volume to a single level?

Comment: Does that only happen when building your project on Android studio?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the duplicates? Because we don't know which duplicates you have seen.

Comment: @AndrewT. 
1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/279407/how-to-disable-microphone-from-auto-adjusting-its-input-volume 
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/689209/how-to-disable-microphone-volume-auto-adjustment-in-cisco-webex

Comment: @vanadium It happens using whenever I am using something that uses the microphone (the emulator in android studio uses the microphone)

Comment: Perhaps clarify your actual question a bit in that respect: use "edit".

Comment: @vanadium I updated the question, can you check it out?