# Disable Auto Adjust microphone in Skype for Linux Beta

Tags: lubuntu, pulseaudio, skype, microphone, volume-control

My question is similar to [How to disable microphone from auto adjusting it's Input volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279407/how-to-disable-microphone-from-auto-adjusting-its-input-volume), but the new Skype for Linux Beta lacks any of the advanced settings about audio or video.

This is how its settings look like:

[image]

Is there any way to disable Auto Adjust by editing a config fail or something like that?

Comment: I have the same the problem. Currently I am using the "bash-loop-hack" to force Pulseaudio to stay in the unamplified area under 100%. Even after this ugly hack the volume is still jumping around noticeably. I really love the new UI of Skype for Linux but this is a real bummer. I am using Fedora btw, the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can adjust the Mic on the top right corner (with the speaker). I am not using lubuntu (just plain ubuntu), so it may be slightly diffrent. But you should be able to adjust the mic settings under System Settings --> Sound --> Input.

Comment: My problem is that Skype keeps adjusting it behind my back. It always puts it at the highest level which adds a lot of static noise.

Comment: Sure that the static noise is skype? Because when I am using my mic, I have every time I use it static. The better the mic is in gerneral, the less static noise there is. If you think this is a bug in skype, write to MS. If you don't have an acc, I can do it for you.