# Disable volume auto adjust in pulseaudio "module-echo-cancel"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, volume-control, echo

**Important:** this question [How to disable microphone from auto adjusting its input volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279407/how-to-disable-microphone-from-auto-adjusting-its-input-volume) doesn't cover this scenario.

This question is about the **volume auto adjust feature of pulseaudio "module-echo-cancel".**

---

I am using the pulseaudio module `module-echo-cancel`, officially documented [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index45h3).

You can enable it by editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and adding the line:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel
```

And reseting it with `pulseaudio -k`. **And it works.**

But the documentation doesn't inform **how to disable the volume auto adjust** that this module executes when it is enabled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_args="analog_gain_control=0 digital_gain_control=0"
```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Enable_Echo.2FNoise-Cancelation

Comment: You really searched deep! Congratulations!

Answer (score 8):

Since the accepted answer is only part of the problem for me, to adjust properly the volume and avoid auto-change, I will give a complementary configuration needed:

## Per-application volume

Sometimes even with `gain_control=0`, pulse resets volume per application. It does that for it defaults to `flat` control. To avoid this behaviour, in the file:

```
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

or

```
 ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Uncomment the line, and set to `no`:

```
flat-volumes = no
```

and restart PulseAudio with:

```
pulseaudio -k ; pulseaudio --start
```

Comment: Thanks, DrBeco for the additional info.

Comment: that time when you google and find your own answer ! :)

Comment: Haha :) At this time you realize how important your contribution was/is. By a tiny answer here and there, we make the Linux and Ubuntu community better :)