# Pulseaudio set the source volume in the default.pa config?

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

In my `/etc/pulse/default.pa` configuration file I have the following settings:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc source_name=echocancel sink_name=echocancel1
set-default-source echocancel
set-source-volume echocancel 65536
```

The echo-cancel module loads just fine, and is set as the default source for the microphone, however the source-volume is not set to 100%, rather the last line doesn't seem to do anything.

Running the last command stand-alone such as `pacmd set-source-volume echocancel 65536` sets the volume to 100% just fine for the source (microphone).

How would I go about setting the volume of the new echo-cancelled source in the loaded configuration files so it persists between restarts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the echo cancel module seems to have auto-adjust volume by default which resets the volume if the module needs to resync or you restart pulse audio.

I added the flags: `aec_args="analog_gain_control=0\ digital_gain_control=1"` to the load line and it seemed to remove the volume readjust.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1069998/574240