# Noise/Echo Cancelling Software for ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: sound, noise, echo

is there any noise cancelling software that filters background noise in ubuntu which can make my mic sound clearer when I record a voice/audio

Comment: This may not solve your issue entirely, but please see: https://theaudacitytopodcast.com/tap012-how-to-remove-noise-with-audacity/ Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. Works pretty good. Install Pulse Audio Volume Control to better make adjustments.

[Realtime noise-removal with PulseAudio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio)

Comment: yea I tried it, it only stops the echo but I keep on getting the sound of my keyboard when typing. any help please

Comment: I have tried for years with this stuff.  Keyboard is non-periodic or doesn't have a steady enough rhythm(unless you are a robot) for the software to "see" it and cancel it out. Only way is a quieter keyboard or a microphone close to your mouth that is made to only pickup close sounds. From a Mechanical Engineering Physics standpoint you can't remove the keyboard noise.

Comment: thanks. I have another question, is there any way I can disable auto mic gain on pulseaudio? after adjusting the volume it automatically jumps to 100% capturing a lot of noise

Comment: try reading this thread.  It might help.  That can be a tricky issue.  Some program probably not PulseAudio is driving your mic up and down. https://askubuntu.com/questions/279407/how-to-disable-microphone-from-auto-adjusting-its-input-volume

Comment: Kenny.  Please share what you found and how you did it.  That helps others who visit this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/lawl/NoiseTorch

NoiseTorch is an easy to use open source application for Linux with PulseAudio or PipeWire. It creates a virtual microphone that suppresses noise, in any application. Use whichever conferencing or VOIP application you like and simply select the NoiseTorch Virtual Microphone as input to torch the sound of your mechanical keyboard, computer fans, trains and the likes. -lawl, github.com/lawl/NoiseTorch/README.md

Linux for everyone showcased it in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzN9rYNeeIU)